# How do I access object values in data mapped from .json using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to use data from an API (https://messi.hyyravintolat.fi/publicapi/restaurant/11/) in my React project. I was able to render each "date" from the API, but how do I render each "name" for each "date" in with this kind of .json (the ones immediately inside the "data" arrays in the API)?

{item.data[name]}

doesn't seem to be the way to do this. Here is the component class I'm using to get and render the data:

```
import React from 'react';
    /*eslint-env jquery*/

class TestMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { food: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.UserList();
  }

  UserList() {
    $.getJSON('https://messi.hyyravintolat.fi/publicapi/restaurant/11/')
      .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ food: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const foods = this.state.food.map((item, i) => (
      <div>
        <h1>{item.date}</h1>
        <p>{item.data[name]}</p>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">{foods}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default TestMenu;
```

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the raw JSON being returned? That will be more helpful in giving you the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I've checked the datasource you provided in your code. The data returned is very heterogeneous. What information are you looking to extract exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, think I get what you're trying to do, will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the datasource, the JSON is in the following shape:

```
[
  {
    "date": some date,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": some name,
        ...
      },
      {
        "name": some other name,
        ...
      }
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": some other date,
    "data": [ ... ]
  },
  ...
]
```

So there are several names for a single date. You could render this like the following:

```
<h1>{item.date}</h1>
<ul>
  {item.data.map((d, idx) => {
    return <li key={idx}>{d.name}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Note that I also use the indices when mapping the data in order to provide a unique `key` to React for each `<li>` element.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need a second loop as `data` (the nested one) is an array and not an object.
A simple example of looping with your data structure:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://messi.hyyravintolat.fi/publicapi/restaurant/11/")
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          list: data.data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            list && list.map((obj) => {
              return (
                <li className="item">
                  <div className="date">
                    <span>Date: </span> <span>{obj.date}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="names">
                    {
                      obj.data.map((obj2) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="name">
                            <span>Name: </span> <span>{obj2.name}</span>
                          </div>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.item {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.date {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.names {
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.name{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution seems to work perfectly as well